# jar file is not working in windows 10

Tags: java, runtime.exec

-My code is used to create and Update the environment path using java with Netbeans and cmd prompt. That is working fine in my output console, BUt when i convert it into jar file that is not working properly. what should i do to work on windows 10. Because it's Working Fine in Windows8 & WIndows7..
 Thanks in Advance...

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      String CreoPath_textfield = Textfield.getText();     
    try {
        rt.exec(new String[]{"CMD.exe", "/C", "setx CREO_PATH \""+CreoPath_textfield+""});           
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Environment_set.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  if(CreoPath_textfield.equals(""))
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><b><font color=red>"+"Please enter Your Creo Path" + "</font></b></html>","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
   else{
    setVisible(false); 
   }
```

Comment: What is the `CREO_PATH` variable? Shouldn't you use the `PATH` variable instead??

Comment: **CREO_PATH** is variable name in system environment vriable.If i type any path in textfield that path will store with name of the **CREO_PATH**   path(For example : C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 2.0).@ J.Baoby

Comment: You did not end the command with a closing quote: `rt.exec(new String[]{"CMD.exe", "/C", "setx CREO_PATH \""+CreoPath_textfield+""});` should probably be ` rt.exec(new String[]{"CMD.exe", "/C", "setx CREO_PATH \""+CreoPath_textfield+"\""});`